# owl-carousel показать сразу конец списка

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Есть плагин owl-carousel, с помощью него выводим слайды, и возможность листать влево / вправо.

Каким образом сделать чтобы по умолчанию, при загрузке страницы, был показан последний слайд, то есть чтобы было так, как будто бы пользователь долистал к конец списка.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```js
var lastItem = $('.item').length - 1;
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  startPosition: lastItem,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>13</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>14</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>15</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>16</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>17</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>18</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>19</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>20</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет, это не подходит. может можно как-то просто сымитировать как будто пользователь долистал до конца?

Comment: @Денис - обновил ответ

Comment: Если слайдеров хотя бы 20, он Где То на середине показывает... Чего то не хватает видимо

Comment: Пример с 20 слайдерами - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/anechqsu/1/